# Difference Between Adrogation and Arrogation?

Tags: definition, sui-juris

#### A Preceding Note:

I do enjoy studying law and legal philosophies from time to time, but I'm not a legal student here or even in the legal sectors, so please try to put any explanation you have into (some degree of) layman's terms.

---

#### The Question, Main Source:

I stumbled onto [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrogation) on Wikipedia about the legal concepts in ancient Roman law of "adrogation" and "arrogation".

It defined the former as a [*sui juris*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sui%20juris) adoption of another person, and the latter as an [*alieni juris*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alieni%20juris) adoption of another person.

> Adrogation, among [ancient Romans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Rome), was a kind of [adoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption) in which the person adopted was free, and consented to be adopted by another. It was done at the assembly of the people while the commonwealth subsisted, and later by a rescript of the [emperors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Empire).
>
> This is contrasted with arrogation, in which one claims another for oneself without the right.

But it only referenced a single source¹, and it wasn't one I have really heard of, so I decided to check other sites to verify.

#### Other Sources

1. Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO) defined "[adrogation](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/adrogation)" as *sui juris* and "[arrogation](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/arrogate)" as *alieni juris*.

> `Adrogation:`
>
> Adoption of a person who is sui juris and hence not subject to the legal power of another.
>
> `Arrogation:`
>
> Take or [claim](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/claim#claim__14) (something) without [justification](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/justification#justification__2)

2. Oxford English Dictionary (OED)² defined "adrogation" as *sui juris* and "arrogation" as both(*???*) *alieni juris* **and** a synonym of *arrogation*. (**How the scrambled eggs can it be both *sui juris* AND *alieni juris*???)**

> `Adrogation:`
>
> Adoption of a person who is sui juris (sui juris n. a) and hence not subject to the legal power of another. Cf. arrogation n. 1.
>
> `Arrogation:`
>
> 1. = adrogation n.   (So usually spelt in this sense.)
> 2. The action of claiming and assuming without just reason; unwarrantable assumption.

3. Merriam-Webster Online defines "[adrogation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adrogation)" as a synonym of "[arrogation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrogate)" (basically the exact opposite of what the ODO did), which is defined as *alieni juris*.

> `Adrogation:`
>
> : arrogation 2
>
> `Arrogation:`
>
> : to take or claim (something, such as a right or a privilege) in a way that is not fair or legal

So which is it? It can't be **both** *sui juris* **and** *alieni juris* adoption.

I'm so confused... @_@

---

¹ Here is the source the Wikipedia article cited:

> [[Public Domain Symbol]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PD-icon.svg) This article incorporates text from a publication now in the public domain: Chambers, Ephraim, ed. (1728). "article name needed". Cyclopædia, or an Universal Dictionary of Arts and Sciences (first ed.). James and John Knapton, et al.

² These require a paying subscription, so I'll just include the links down here so as not to mislead anyone.

- [Adrogation](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2772?redirectedFrom=adrogation#eid)
- [Arrogation](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11064#eid38921134)